# File not coming back decrypted

Tags: c++

I have a simple program that takes a file and encrypts it until you answer two questions, but the file never gets unencrypted.

```
char normal[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
char encrypted[] = {'t', 'h', 'e', 'q', 'u', 'i', 'c', 'k', 'b', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n', 'f', 'x', 'j', 'u', 'm', 'p', 'd', 'v', 'l', 'a', 'z', 'y', 'g'};


int main() {
  cout << "Welcome to file proofreader!" << endl << "Once you choose a file,  we will proofread it and return a copy to you with our" << endl << "corrections." << endl;
  cout << "Please choose a file to proofread: ";
  string filename;
  cin >> filename;
  encrypt(filename);
  cout << "GOTCHA! Your file has been encrypted. Your file will be lost forever unless you answer the following questions correctly!" << endl;
  complete = quiz();
  decrypt(filename);
  cout << "Fine, I guess you can have your file back. " << endl;
  return 0;
}

void encrypt(string filename) {
  ifstream input;
  input.open(filename.c_str());
  ofstream output;
  output.open("GOTCHA.txt");
  char c;
  while (input.get(c)) {
    tolower(c);
    output << encrypted[c-97];
  }
  input.close();
  output << endl;
  output.close();
  ofstream other;
  other.open(filename);
  other << "GOTCHA!" << endl;
  other.close();
 }

void decrypt(string filename) {
  ifstream input;
  input.open("GOTCHA.txt");
  ofstream output;
  output.open(filename.c_str());
  char c;
  while (input.get(c)) {
    int idx = findIdxInEncrypted(c);
    output << normal[idx];
  }
  input.close();
  output << endl;
  output.close();
}

 int findIdxInEncrypted(char c) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
   if (c == encrypted[i]) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

bool quiz (){
  cout << endl;
  cout << "What color is the sky? " << endl << endl;
  cout << "A) Blue" << endl;
  cout << "B)/> Green" << endl;
  cout << "C) Red" << endl;
  cout << "D) Purple" << endl;
  char answer;
  cin >> answer;
  if (answer == 'a' || answer == 'A') {
    cout << "Correct" << endl;
  }
  else
    cout << "Incorrect" << endl;
  cout << endl;                                                                                 
  cout << "What color is grass? " << endl;
  cout << "A) Blue" << endl;
  cout << "B)/> Green" << endl;
  cout << "C) Red" << endl;
  cout << "D) Purple" << endl;
  cin >> answer;
  if (answer == 'b' || answer == 'B'){
      cout << "Correct" << endl;
     }
  else
    cout << "Incorrect" << endl;
  cout << endl;

 return true;
}
```

The GOTCHA.txt looks like this tkbp^@fuuqp^@dx^@mvf^P and the file passed to it looks like this ahis^@needs^@to^@run^@^@.

It is suppose to say 'This needs to run'.

Comment: Okay so what debugging have you performed to isolate the problem?

Comment: `tolower` does not modify its argument; it returns the lowercase character. You're also "encrypting" everything, not just the alphabetical characters, which will cause out-of-bounds array accesses.

Comment: This is not encryption. Please don't call and tag such system encryption. Valid name for this might be obfuscation.

Comment: this question is about malware and the creation of it. I hope you never achieve your goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly as @molbdnilo mentioned you need to use tolower appropriately.

```
int x = tolower(c);
output << encrypted[x - 97];
```

Do not encrypt the non-alphabetic characters. You can check for non alphabetic characters using isalpha()
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/

Be sure to leave non alphabetic characters as is while decrypting as you won't be encrypting them. You only have provision to encrypt lower case alphabets in your code.

Even while decrypting put up a condition to check for alphabets.

And thirdly, I don't see the use of the

```
complete = quiz();
```

You haven't established any kind of answer checking anyway. It would make sense to check if the answers are correct. You function quiz() will always end up returning true.

If you have any questions, let me know :)